# Write sql data to csv from python API

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I am running SQL query from python API and want to collect data in Structured(column-wise data under their own header).CSV format.

This is the code so far I have.

```
import pymysql.cursors
import csv


conn = pymysql.connect(host='159.XXX.XXX.XXX',user='proXXX',password='PXX',db='pXX',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = conn.cursor()
print (type(conn))
sql = "SELECT id,author From researches WHERE id < 20 " 
cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchall()
print (data)
with open('metadata.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_handle:
    writer = csv.writer(f_handle,delimiter=',')
    header = ['id', 'author']
    writer.writerow(header)
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Now the data is being printed on the console but not getting in.CSV file this is what I am getting asn[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyGpf.png). What is that I am missing? Please help.

Comment: You're calling this code in a loop?

Comment: Yes, is there a better way.?

Comment: You should use the `a` mode, otherwise you re-write your file each time. Also, write your headers just once...

Comment: I am very new to this. Can you please help me with the code?

Comment: Maybe... if you could update your question to include how this code is called - I want to see the loop, and any other relevant code, so I can show you how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('metadata.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_handle:
    fieldnames = ['id', 'author']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_handle, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

So the thing is, your data is in the form of dictionaries, while the Writer object expects tuples. You should be using the DictWriter object instead.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @JerryTheo

Comment: A simple question. My database contains a column named as published_date but I want the header (Fieldname)to be as "Published Date". I tried and it is throwing an error.Is it possible to get the desired header?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I've had a lot on my hands this week. Anyway, there are two ways you can do this, you either replace the key in the dictionary for each of the rows, or you can skip `writer.writeheader()` and use this instead, `writer.writerow({'id': 'id', 'author': 'author', 'published_date': 'Published Date'})`.